# what are some of the success stories of applying optimization in computer vision?

Tags: optimization, computer-vision

I'm trying to find several examples that demonstrate the success of optimization methods in application to computer vision and robotics. In particular, I'm interested in problems I can formulate from scratch and use existing optimization methods (e.g. [cvxopt](http://cvxopt.org/) library in python). What would be a good example?